# steam API with PHP from JSON h

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Please help me,
this html code is in a loop but when i submit the form for fetching the price i.e `get-price` button, the price is always coming in first element of `h1` tag 
loop starts

```
<form method="post"  class="frm">
    <input type="hidden" name="rom" value="<?php echo $hash;?>" />

<input type="submit" value='get-price'  />
</form>
<h1 id="response"> </h1>
loopends
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".frm").submit(function(e){ //user clicks form submit button

    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //prepare form data for Ajax post
    var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]'); //get clicked button info
    button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text //change button text 

    $.ajax({ //make ajax request to cart_process.php
        url: "getprice.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data
    }).done(function(data){ 
       $("#response").html(data);
      console.log(data);
        //this.element = $('#response');



    })
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```